# Using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS no sound in select apps

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa, mute

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and for some reason I get no sound whatsoever in a few programs. VLC, Hydrogen, GNOME MPlayer, and Movie Player work fine, but Banshee, Rythmbox, Chromium, Konquerer and Firefox have no sound. The system makes that bubble-thingy sound at startup and the System Testing for the audio works. It's all very strange.

The problem affects the program no matter how I listen (speakers or headphone jack) on my laptop.

I have tested/checked the alsamixer (`alsamixer`) to make sure that the sound isn't muted.

This is rather annoying and I would like to fix it, help!

**EDIT:**

Here's what I get in terminal when I start Banshee via `banshee`

```
[Info  18:00:10.944] Running Banshee 2.4.1: [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (linux-gnu, i686) @ 2012-07-17 02:32:36 UTC]
[Warn  18:00:16.206] Caught an exception - System.ApplicationException: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached. (in `Banshee.MultimediaKeys')
at Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService.Banshee.ServiceStack.IExtensionService.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.StartExtension (Mono.Addins.TypeExtensionNode node) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Warn  18:00:16.207] Extension `Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService' not started: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached.
[Info  18:00:16.229] Updating web proxy from GConf
[Warn  18:00:16.277] Caught an exception - System.ApplicationException: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached. (in `Banshee.MultimediaKeys')
at Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService.Banshee.ServiceStack.IExtensionService.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.StartExtension (Mono.Addins.TypeExtensionNode node) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Warn  18:00:16.277] Extension `Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService' not started: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached.
[Info  18:00:16.279] All services are started 4.343458
[Info  18:00:17.015] AmazonMP3 store redirect URL: https://one.ubuntu.com/music/store/amz/
[Info  18:00:18.672] nereid Client Started
[Info  18:00:18.932] GStreamer version 0.10.36.0, gapless: True, replaygain: False
```

Comment: what architecture you are using 32 bit or 64 ? I think its thr problem of drivers and compatility issue

Comment: Have you tried to start them from the terminal and check if you get any error/warning printed? Also you have double-checked this is not a codec problem, right? (as Rhythmbox and totem use the same "backend" it is very unlikely...)

Comment: @YousafEhsan I am using the 32 bit architecture.

Comment: @Salem I edited the question for banshee. I have to go eat and then I will do the Rythmbox one

Comment: What do you have in this tab in sound configuration? http://i.stack.imgur.com/DFZin.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'll post my comment as a answer as I fixed it:

Maybe you have this configuration in silence:

[image: Configuration window]